# Contract's methods returns empty object

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I have a smart contract with a few methods on it.
I am trying to run `truffle develop`, then `compile` and `migrate` my contract and using generated **ABI** and **contract address** to connect on web app using `web3`

The develop is running on port 9545

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const contractInstance new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
```

Here `contractInstance.methods` is `{ }`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before where the ABI was wrong. Just make sure you have the ABI correctly.